# New ways to update my windows application over internet

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce, auto-update

I am aware of "Click once approach", I find a problem with its one year certificate, and if I want to have more than one year certificate, I have to purchase the certificate from them.

I want to know, If there is any way to address this, So i can have my clients get updates for many years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate a ClickOnce certificate with any expiration date (and any Issued To/Issued By values):

```
makecert -sv ClickOnceTestApp.pvk
     -n CN=Sample ClickOnceTestApp.cer
     -b 01/01/2012 -e 12/31/2100 -r
```

It will be a self-signed certificate, same as generated by Visual Studio for click once deployments.

from http://bernhardelbl.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/create-a-non-expiring-test-certificate-pfx-for-clickonce-applications/

Comment: Is this an illegal thing to create certificate like this?

Comment: It is definitely not illegal (creating any certificate is not illegal :). However, that certificate will be "not trusted" on end user machine (same as the certificate you are using currently, generated by VS). End user will receive a warning "Publisher cannot be verified". Purchasing a certificate assumes that certificate authority will validate your identity, so end user will know that app is actually published by you. Certificate providers takes money for identity validation (and confirmation), not for just running makecert on theirs machines.